# How can solve Unrecognized escape sequence?

Tags: c#

I have this code for getting between string:

```
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    int Start, End;
    if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
    {
        Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
        End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and this is my string data:

> FHTT-04ce1068
>   GP\u0001\u001b10001182-2100113j6J2-FTTH\b\u0006??0?-\u0006

I want find the substring into that data, for that purpose write this code:

```
string userName = getBetween(theData,"GP\u0001\u001", "\b\u0006??0?");
```

but get this error:

> Unrecognized escape sequence

change that code to this:

```
string userName = getBetween(theData,@"GP\u0001\u001", "\b\u0006??0?");
```

but `@` add the double escape for a search string and that code doesn't work correctly, how can I solve that problem?

my source in this link:
[Main Source](http://rextester.com/PWDCL23665)

Comment: You need `@` on both arguments, you only have it on the first. (assuming the file actually contains the escape sequences as text)

Comment: use \\ instead of \

Comment: @viveknuna not work

Comment: @stackstack use for both parameters

Comment: In your input text, is `\u0001` 1 char or 6 ? In other words, what does NotePad(++) show?

Comment: @HenkHolterman 6 character

Comment: @HenkHolterman notepad++ show \u0001

Comment: @ does not double the escape.  Print out the value with a Debug statement.

Comment: I hope you didn't copy from a VisualStudio debugger window. You need to look at the primary source.

Comment: Since none of the answers seem to work, it's time for a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [verbatim identifier (`@`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) symbol for both strings.

With string literals, it basically means that the `\` chars are considered a part of the string, as apposed to non-verbatim string literals, where it serves as an escape char. (Please note that in a verbatim literal string, if you want to include the `"` char as a part of the string, you escape it by doubling - `var s = @"this is my ""special"" string";`)

<strike>The reason your getBetween method doesn't return the expected value is that the method itself has a bug.</strike>

In your getBetween method you have some redundant code, so here is an improved version:

```
public static string GetBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    var Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart) + strStart.Length;
    var End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
    if (Start > strStart.Length -1 && End > -1)
    {
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
    return "";
}
```

And the usage:

```
var source = @"FHTT-04ce1068 GP\u0001\u001b10001182-2100113j6J2-FTTH\b\u0006??0?-\u0006";
var target = GetBetween(source, @"GP\u0001\u001", @"\b\u0006??0?");
```

Result:

```
b10001182-2100113j6J2-FTTH
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/PMDI96073)

Here is what I've improved from your original method:

```
// Capitalize the method name according to c# naming conventions.
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    int Start, End;
    // no point of checking if the string contains the values, IndexOf will return -1 if it doesn't.
    if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
    {
        // You don't need to specify that 0, IndexOf other overload already starts from zero.
        Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
        End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
    // else is redundant since there is a return statement in the if.
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

### Update

The problem is that the string you search on is already full with escape sequences, including a couple of `\"` - so adding the verbatim identifier to that string will actually cause a compilation error.

On the other hand, if you don't use the verbatim literal on the search string, you can't use it on the other strings - and that might cause a problem - since it means that the other strings can't be just random parts of the original string - they must have the escape sequences correct - and `"GP\u0001\u001"` does not - the last escape sequence is missing it's last char - the `b` you got in the results is actually a part of `\u0001b` - so if you do the search like this:

```
var source = "\0PV?-M\0$??E?\b\0E\0\u0003???\0\0\u001d\u0011?)????\n\n\u0005g?H\a\u0015\u0003???\u0004s\u0003?S]pfX?\a?????H???U\u0006\0\0\u0001,.\u0006\0\u0011S?(\u0006\0\0\0\u00037\u0006Z???=\u0006\0\0\0%\u001a\u001e\0\0\0\t\u0001\u0018pppoe-session-id=39703\u001a)\0\0\0\t\u0001#client-mac-address=f08c.fbce.07fb\u001a=\0\0\r?\u000170 0/0/0:1250.1059 AN5516-01/3/6/2/0/3/FHTT04ce07f8 GP\u001aL\0\0\0\t\u0001Fcircuit-id-tag=0 0/0/0:1250.1059 AN5516-01/3/6/2/0/3/FHTT04ce07f8 GP,\n0019a97b\u0005\u0006\u0001\b?'W80 0/0/0:1250.1059 AN5516-01/3/6/2/0/3/FHTT04ce07f8 GP.\u001a>\0\0\0\t\u000280 0/0/0:1250.1059 AN5516-01/3/6/2/0/3/FHTT04ce07f8 GP.\u001e70 0/0/0:1250.1059 AN5516-01/3/6/2/0/3/FHTT04ce07f8 GP\u0001\u001b10001084-2100101Db75-FTTH\b\u0006??0?-\u0006\0\0\0\u0001\u001a\u0016\0\0\0\t\u0001\u0010vrf-id=default\u001a\u001f\0\0\0\t\u0001\u0019accounting-list=ibs-isg\a\u0006\0\0\0\u0001\u0006\u0006\0\0\0\u0002?\u0006\0\0\0C\u001a\"\0\0\0\t\u0001\u001cconnect-progress=IPCP Open*\u0006\u001c???4\u0006\0\0\0\u0001/\u0006\u0001Yb?+\u0006?kTJ5\u0006\0\0\0\b0\u0006\u0001???\u001a)\0\0\0\t\u0001#acct-input-octets-ipv4=4092795251\u001a(\0\0\0\t\u0001\"acct-input-packets-ipv4=22540221\u001a*\0\0\0\t\u0001$acct-output-octets-ipv4=1916952698\u001a$\0\0\0\t\u0001\u001eacct-output-gigawords-ipv4=8\u001a)\0\0\0\t\u0001#acct-output-packets-ipv4=28406963\u001a \0\0\0\t\u0001\u001aacct-input-octets-ipv6=0\u001a!\0\0\0\t\u0001\u001bacct-input-packets-ipv6=0\u001a!\0\0\0\t\u0001\u001bacct-output-octets-ipv6=0\u001a\"\0\0\0\t\u0001\u001cacct-output-packets-ipv6=0 \u0005ASR\u0004\u0006????_\u0012\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0)\u0006\0\0\0\0";
var target = GetBetween(
    source, 
    "GP\u0001\u001b", // Note I've added that `b`!
    "\b\u0006??0?");
```

You will get this result:

```
10001084-2100101Db75-FTTH
```

Comment: Why there is no error in source without @ and there is error in first argument without @

Comment: please wait to test that.

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj Because there are no invalid escape in that string.  The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: nope, I am bit confused. argument 1 is part of that source text. then y source doesnot have that problem...? just to learn things i am asking

Comment: If you get the string from an external resource such as a website or a file, it's no longer a string literal, so you don't need to escape or verbatim it. I've added some information about the `@` symbol to my question. If that's not enough, you should visit the link and read the official documentation.

Comment: thanks,my source in the this link please review that http://rextester.com/PWDCL23665

Comment: I've seen it. The problem is that your source string is already full with escape sequences; including a couple of `\"` - once you change it to a verbatim string, the `"` inside are no longer escaped and the entire thing crash.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: The last part of the answer, right after the big bold "Update" title :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `\\` instead of `\` or use `@` with both the parameters of `getBetween` method

Comment: @stackstack: Can you please elaborate why that does not work for you? It is a known solution to the error that you're encountering.